# Android. adb tcpip 5555 : error: device not found. win8 platform

Tags: android, adb, windows-8.1

I am new to Android development. I am using Dell laptop computer running Windows 8.1 Pro as the development machine, and my Moto E running Android 4.4.4 as the testing device. 
On running the application in Eclipse, Android AVD Error pops up saying "No Compatible Targets found".  I cannot find my running android device in the Android Device Chooser. I have connected it using USB. USB Debugging is enabled. I don't know where I am going wrong. 
I tried connecting using wireless through cmd. adb tcpip 5555 gives error: device not found.

I have tried all the fixes/workarounds available on the internet. 
1. adb kill-server followed by adb start-server
2. restarting cmd
3. checking the drivers to be up to date. 
4. The device manager does show my device : which means that the device is indeed connected.

Is there any way I can check where I am going wrong? why would the device not be found connected?

I have downloaded the latest drivers from: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481. I am using  Eclipse ADT Bundle downloaded from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html for app development.

I have followed all the links given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408674/adb-error-device-not-found

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:

android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is can't install APK not is connected your real device or emulator. you can to check you AndroidManifest.xml targetApiVersion=? because if you set api 19 below that cause unsupported.

Comment: it says 21. 
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="21"

Comment: go sdk Manager install the api file. @neha

Comment: run SDK Manager install USB driver in extra then try plug off/on and adb kill-server adb devices on adb shell environment

Comment: I have done that 17Coder 
@whho done all these. adb shell also gives error: device not found

Comment: Do you have install driver for Moto E?

Comment: @whho yes. the one from the link given above.

Comment: try it. https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/99012/p/30,6720,9146

Comment: can you transfer data(e.g. picture) from phone to PC? can you show your SDK Manager window?

Answer (score 0):

Create AVD that supports android-4(Android 1.6) or change your android-4 target to android-8.

How to create new AVD ?

on Eclipse, [Window> Android AVD Manager] select,

you press the [new] button, you can create new Android Virtual Device

[Managing AVDs with AVD Manager here](https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)

Comment: It says: Unfortunately, HelloWorld has stopped.

Comment: @neha  it means emulator is running. check proper ur manifest file and xml.

Comment: I have pasted the contents of manifest file. can you help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: ur manifest is correct.  logcat ?  there i will find out whats exactly error comes..

Comment: follow this link step by step and copy paste ka code in Hello World program.after run   hopefully ur hello world works..                             http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm

Comment: Installation failed due to invalid URI! it says. lemme do it again.

Comment: try this please @neha     Project (right click)  -> Clean